# Adding element to List from csv file like Arraylist.add

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
public static Map<String, List<Customer>> readCustomerData() throws IOException {
    
    Map<String, List<Customer>> customers =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("customer.csv"))
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
            .map(field -> new Customer(
                    Integer.parseInt(field[0]), field[1],
                    Integer.parseInt(field[2]), field[3]))
            .collect(Collectors
                    .groupingBy(Customer::getName));
    System.out.println (customers);
    
    return customers;
}
```

I notice that this code read my data in the csv file into one element like this:

```
(Ali = ["1 Ali 1201345673 Normal"] , Siti = ["2 Siti 1307891435 Normal"])
```

But in my thinking , I would like to read the data like the array list such as for Ali: 1 is an element ,  Ali is an element , 1201345673 is an element and Normal is another element in the list in the Map customer. How can I modify my code to do such a thing?

This is my Customer class just in case:

```
public class Customer {
private int customerNo;
private String name;
private int phoneNo;
private String status;
public Customer () {}
public Customer (int customerNo, String name, int phoneNo, String status){
    this.customerNo = customerNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    this.status = status;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String toString(){
    return customerNo + " " + name + " " + phoneNo + " " + status;
}
```

Here is my csv file:

```
1,Ali,1201345673,Normal
2,Siti,1307891435,Normal
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the customer names are unique, there's no need to return a `Map<String, List<Customer>>`, since each `List` will contain a single `Customer`.

You can change your code to:

```
Map<String, Customer> customers =
Files.lines(Paths.get("customer.csv"))
        .map(line -> line.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
        .map(field -> new Customer(
                Integer.parseInt(field[0]), field[1],
                Integer.parseInt(field[2]), field[3]))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getName, Function.identity()));
```

And if the names are not unique, you can index the customers by the customer IDs.

As for `I would like to read the data like the array list such as for Ali: 1 is an element , Ali is an element , 1201345673 is an element and Normal is another element in the list in the Map customer` - this doesn't make sense to me. You already create a `Customer` object from each line of your input, which is much more useful and type safe compared to a `List` of properties.

Comment: The reason I would like to talk about this is because I have one code like this : List<Customer> search = customers.get(signInName); where user enter name and we found the data of the name and output it with aligned data but it output only one element which is :"1 , Ali , 1201345673 , Normal" and I can't do the aligned format.

Comment: Asking another question , what does Function.identity do?

Comment: @WeiJunTee Function.identity() is a function that returns the argument you pass to it. It's equivalent to the lambda expression x -> x.

Comment: "1 Ali 1201345673 Normal" is simply what the toString() method of Customer class returns. If you have a problem with that, change it.

Comment: So how can I change the toString() method?

Comment: When I change my code to yours then how can I us the List<Customer> search = customers.get(signInName)?

Comment: It will return a single Customer: `Customer search = customers.get(signInName);`

Comment: If I wanna get multiple result?

Comment: to get all customers, you can use `Collection<Customer> allCusts = customers.values();`